# How to populate field only with Users who have a certain role in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-1.4

So I'm working on this simple ticket management system, I have two entities, `User` which has fields `id, email, roles[] (Admin, Technician or Client)`, and `username, password, tickets[] (which are all the tickets the client has submitted)`.
I Have a `TicketFormType` class that allows me to create new tickets and assign `a technician to that ticket`, here is the code for it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Title',
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Ticket title']
        ])
        ->add('priority', ChoiceType::class, [
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices' => [
                'Very High' => 5,
                'High' => 4,
                'Medium' => 3,
                'Low' => 2,
                'Very Low' => 1
            ]
        ])
        ->add('body')
        ->add('assignmentDate')
        ->add('technician') // this field gets populated with all users including those who don't have ROLE_TECHNICIAN
        ->add('customer')
    ;
}
```

Now in my db structure, I have `ticket table` that has these fields `id     technician_id   customer_id     title   priority    body    assignment_date` where `technician_id` is a FK to a PK in`table user`, my problem is that the technician field which is a dropdown gets populated with all users of `User table` including those who don't have `ROLE_TECHNICIAN`. How do I solve this?

```
NOTE: I store all technicians, clients, admins in table Users
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a QueryBuilder like so:

```
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Title',
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Ticket title']
        ])
        ->add('priority', ChoiceType::class, [
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices' => [
                'Very High' => 5,
                'High' => 4,
                'Medium' => 3,
                'Low' => 2,
                'Very Low' => 1
            ]
        ])
        ->add('body')
        ->add('assignmentDate')
        ->add('technician') // this field gets populated with all users including those who don't have ROLE_TECHNICIAN
        ->add('technician', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => User::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->andWhere('u.ROLE LIKE :role')
                    ->setParameter('role', '%\'ROLE_TECHNICIAN\'%');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'username',
        ])
        ->add('customer')
    ;
```

You'll have to adapt this to your needs.